# parse string input to date with javaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I am currently working on a project and am very new to Java and have a really hard time understanding how it works compared to languages like C#.

**What I need to to is take a user submitted date (string) and verify that it is MM/DD/YYYY format using JavaFX.**

I have been googling how to do this for some time, but none of the solutions i have found seem to work.

**Here is the GUI:** http://puu.sh/bZcmg/8a33901e28.png

**And this is my controller(so far):**

```
public class FXMLNewLabSchedulerDocController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TextField txtRequestorName;
    @FXML
    private TextField txtRequestorEmail;
    @FXML
    private TextField txtEventTitle;
    @FXML
    private TextField txtNumParticipants;
    @FXML
    private TextField txtEventDate;
    @FXML
    private TextField txtStartTime;
    @FXML
    private TextField txtEndTime;
    @FXML
    private ToggleButton togStartTime;
    @FXML
    private ToggleButton togEndTime;
    @FXML
    private CheckBox chkPrinter;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton rbYes;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton rbNo;
    @FXML
    private TextArea txtareaMessage;


    @FXML
    private void handleBtnSubmit(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("You clicked me!");
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleBtnClear(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Clear All Fields!");
        txtRequestorName.setText("");
        txtRequestorEmail.setText("");
        txtEventTitle.setText("");
        txtNumParticipants.setText("");
        txtEventDate.setText("");
        txtStartTime.setText("");
        txtEndTime.setText("");
        chkPrinter.setSelected(false);
        rbYes.setSelected(false);
        rbNo.setSelected(false);
        txtareaMessage.setText("");
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleBtnClose(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Application Close!");
        Platform.exit();
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        txtareaMessage.editableProperty().bind(rbYes.selectedProperty());
    }    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Impossible

Regardless of Java or other development environments, there is no way to do this perfectly. Is `01/02/2014` January first or February second? Impossible to know. You either have to:

- Trust the user to get it right. Perhaps provide feedback such as a visual calendar or spelling out the date as text.
- Provide a date-picker tool rather than rely on typed input.

You can see if what they typed is *not* in that format. Attempt to convert the string to a date data type. If an an incorrect format exception is thrown, then you know the user got it wrong. If no exception is thrown, then *maybe* the user got it right.

As I recall, JavaFX includes a date-picker widget. I suggest you consider using that or another third-party widget.

## Avoid j.u.Date

Starting with early versions of Java, you'll find the java.util.Date and java.util.Calendar classes along with java.text.SimpleDateFormat. Avoid these classes. They are notoriously troublesome, flawed in both design and implementation.

Instead use either:

- The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library.
- The [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html)
  (bundled with Java 8, inspired by Joda-Time, defined by JSR 310).

## Date-Only

To verify the date you need a date-only class, without any time-of-day or time zone. Both Joda-Time and java.time offer a [`LocalDate`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) class for this purpose, while java.util.Date/Calendar does not.

## Joda-Time

Example code using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.4.

```
String input = "01/02/2014";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "M/d/yyyy" ); // Single `M` and `d` allows user to enter single or double digits.
LocalDate localDate = null;
try {
    localDate = formatter.parseLocalDate( input );
} catch ( IllegalArgumentException e ) {
    // FIXME: Handle the user input in wrong format.
}
```

Generate text as feedback to the user.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatterOutput = DateTimeFormat.forStyle( "F-" ).withLocale( Locale.US );
String output = formatterOutput.print( localDate );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "input: " + input );
System.out.println( "localDate: " + localDate );
System.out.println( "output: " + output );
```

When run.

```
input: 01/02/2014
localDate: 2014-01-02
output: Thursday, January 2, 2014
```

Bonus tips: Learn about the [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) class, [`Interval`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html) class, [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), and [time zones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Your question is really a duplicate, with these topics handled in many many Questions and Answers here on StackOverflow. So search to do more learning.